# How can I hide Home in my menu in a specific page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know how can I hide the home in the menu without setting show_home in functions.php to false, I just want to do is hide it in a specific page. How can I do this? :)

Comment: How secure does this have to be? Would it be acceptable to simply hide this using CSS, or does it have to be entirely absent form the source code?

Comment: absent from the source code? what css code then? not including the bar just the home link ^^

Comment: You misunderstand me - I need to know whether it is acceptable for it simply to be hidden, or whether it must be removed from the HTML altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise hiding it with CSS:

```
.page-item-X.menu-item-Y { display: none; }
```

X = Page ID
Y = Menu item ID

This would be the easiest and simplest way of doing things.

Comment: If you view the source code for the page, you should see the body has a class of `page-id-X`. The numeric value at the end of that class is the page ID.

Comment: I didn't create page yet I use the default index.php of the twenty eleven theme

Comment: Create the page first. Once the page has been created, view the page in your browser and 'view source' for that page. There should be a long list of classes for the body tag, one of which will be `page-id-X`.